# Typing wrong method in migration name in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, xampp, migration

I've created a migration by laravel.
My migration code like this:

```php
Schema::create('members', function (Blueprint $table) {
   // others 
   $table->timestamp('join_date')->userCurrent();
});
```

I've a syntax error in migration `userCurrent()` (correct method is `useCurrent()`). But when I run `php artisan migrate`, it didn't throw any exception. And I also have a factory file is `MemberFactory.php`. I've tried run `php artisan db:seed` on my localhost via `xampp` and it worked.

This is result when I run `desc members` in phpMyAdmin:
[image]

You see that `join_date` column has `current_timestamp()` in `auto_increment` column. I saw that I thought everything worked fine but today, on another PC ( I've used MySQL directly, not via `xampp`), when I run `php artisan db:seed`, it throw an exception that `join_date` column don't have default value.

I checked in my database, it showed this:
[image]

There is no default value in `join_date` column. I've read on some resource that `xampp` using `MariaDB` instead of `MySQL`. It seem easy to fix my problem, but my code was merged to `master` develop and I don't know how I should fix this. I don't want to keep `userCurrent()` in my code but code in `master` is automatic run migration via git CI/CD on another server.

What is best soltion for this? Please help.

Comment: create a new migration that will modify the column and then migrate again. laravel doc [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#modifying-columns).

Comment: @zahidhasanemon, LOL, what a simple solution. Don't know why ask this question. Thanks